# Send a vibration to a SmartWatch 2 App

Tags: android, android-intent, sony, sony-smartwatch

I've been trying for a while and I can't send a vibration to my SmartWatch 2. I'm just editing one of the sample codes, so it would be relatively easy.
This is the code fragment:

```
// Show something
            TextView prueba = (TextView)sensorLayout.findViewById(R.id.prueba);
            if(Math.abs(values[0])>Math.abs(values[1]) & Math.abs(values[0]) > Math.abs(values[2])) {
                prueba.setText("Hacia un lado");
                startVibrator(1000,500, 3); // Does nothing.

            }
            else if(Math.abs(values[1])>Math.abs(values[0]) & Math.abs(values[1]) > Math.abs(values[2])) {
                prueba.setText("Hacia delante o hacia atrás");
            }
            else {
                prueba.setText("Horizontal");
            }
```

The messages are working, but the vibration never do.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct to me.  Only possibilities I can think of here are:

1. The startVibrator method is not being called.  Are you sure it's going into the "if" statement?
2. The vibration on your watch is broken.

Comment: 1. Yup, the message is been displayed
2. It is not broken, when the device is paired or disconnected, it vibrates.

Comment: Hmm ok.  What version of the host app are you using?  What version of Android is the phone running?